# Does the GD2 extension come with PHP?

Tags: php, gd, gd2

Does the GD2 extension come with PHP by default? If yes, since what version does it happen? Is it enabled by default?

thanks (:

Comment: `(PHP 4 >= 4.0.7, PHP 5)` ... although I am not 100% sure.

Comment: hmm, i don't think so...the manual suggests that GD(one) does not come with php until version 4.3. unfortunately it doesn't give me any clue about GD2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GD isn't compiled with PHP by default but is included with many binary distributions of PHP.

Full details/instructions are here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.setup.php

Answer (score 5):

On windows system, it is generally delivered but not installed. You can enable it by decommenting the section in the php.ini file.

On Linux systems (Debian & Ubuntu), on a default installation, it is activated. 
Rather than doing it in command line as suggests : Atticus, give it a try with a php info!

```
<?php 
    phpinfo();
?>
```

If GD is installed, you'll see it on that page. ;)

Comment: also you can do "php -i" this command in terminal to see your phpinfo.

Comment: Or even better: `php -i|grep GD`. This will show you only the `GD` related info.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I think i had to install mine on my server

do you have access to your server or is it a shared server?

If so -- check if php5-gd is installed

Comment: my doubt is merely informative. i need the info for a paperwork and i couldn't find it objetively in the manual :(

Comment: you can install php5-gd with the following command. If it doesn't exist, it will download. If it exists, it will not download again. "sudo yum install php5-gd"